# How do i resolve this warning junit5 throws when i run Parameterized tests?

Tags: android, android-studio, junit5

I get this warning in my test console when i run test cases annotated with @ParameterizedTest

"org.junit.platform.launcher.core.InternalTestPlan add
WARNING: Attempt to modify the TestPlan was detected. A future version of the JUnit Platform will ignore this call and eventually even throw an exception. Please contact your IDE/tool vendor and request a fix (see https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1732 for details)."

How do i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the link in the error message, it would seem that:

> IntelliJ IDEA is affected, fix is on its way: JetBrains/intellij-community#1030

Following that link, it seems that it should be fixed in the 2019.1 release of IntelliJ.

Comment: I already checked the link, and the issue has been open since January so i am assuming there isn't a solution yet.